# Is BlobstoreService thread-safe?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

Does anybody know whether BlobstoreService is thread-safe?
I am asking that because I couldn't find any comments about regarding the subject in the javadocs, yet there is an example in the official documentation where an instance of Blobstore service is stored in a servlet field:

```
public class Serve extends HttpServlet {
    private BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
```

PS:
Actually, before posting this question I have found the exact question on the code.google.com site, but unfortunately it is unanswered: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All services on GAE run on external servers and are accessed via API which is just a RPC wrapper to those services. So whenever you call getXyzService(), you just get a piece of code that starts preparing a RPC call to server.

Afaik, those are all thread safe.

**Update:** In your case you hold an [implementation `BlobstoreService` object](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreServiceImpl.java). Check source to see how it works. It has no internal state (class fields), so it is thread safe.